# percolate returns empty matches under heavy load during elasticsearch cluster resizing

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch cluster dynamically re-sizing in respect to percolate message count in a rabbitmq queue.

We have a single shard and ~18K query in our index, and we use auto_expand_replicas: "0-all" at index settings to copy single shard to all nodes when a node becomes available.

But during heavy load and cluster re-sizing, some requests produces unexpected empty matches.

We send ~1M percolate request daily and we were losing ~1K content. We added a cluster status control to our code, if cluster status is not green before and after percolate request we're waiting for green status and re-sending percolate request, we were able to reduce lost content count from 1K to ~100 in this way. We do not live this problem in a cluster with fixed node size.

Unfortunately any loss is not acceptable in our scenario, and we don't want to give up auto scaling, we need to find a workaround for this problem.

To repeat problem, you can use following bash script:

https://gist.github.com/ekesken/de41598a1e7e54c6f33c

This script will download and install elasticsearch 1.5.2 on your current directory, create a cluster with 10 nodes on your local and create index and percolation queries and will start testing.

Normally we expect following output for single percolate request:

```sh
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_percolate' -d '{  
         "doc" : { 
             "message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office" 
         }   
     }'  
{"took":95,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"total":1,"matches":[{"_index":"my-index","_id":"tree"}]}
```

After running script, if you see all shards in all nodes are started at http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards response and test script is still running, that means you couldn't reproduce problem, try increasing node count which was 10 by default:

```sh
./repeat_percolation_loss.sh 15 test-only
```

When you reproduce problem, script will exit with following output:

```sh
{"took":209,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"total":0,"matches":[]}
Problem repeated! Congratulations.
```

You can shutdown all servers and clean all directory and files created via script with command:

```sh
./repeat_percolation_loss.sh 15 clean
```

Change node count above with latest node count you've tried.

Comment: Did you reproduce the problem with an older version of ES eg 1.4.x ? I saw in the github issue (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10722) that you were both running 1.5.x

Comment: yes, our production environment is 1.1.0 indeed, I did not test 1.4.x versions especially but you can try repeat_percolation_loss.sh script with any version of elasticsearch by changing ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION variable at the beginning of file.